# Adding GridDropdownColumn to Radgrid detail table

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am binding a detail table in DetailTableDataBind event of a Radgrid. The event handler contains code to bind it to a linqdatasource. This adds a bunch of GridBoundColumns to the detail table. However i want some of these to be GridDropdownColumns. How do i go about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch off the auto-generated columns for the detail table and setup GridDropDownColumn where needed. Check out these samples on the Telerik site for details:

[Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/columntypes/defaultcs.aspx)

[Help topic for GridDropDownColumn configure](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grdcustomizeconfiguregriddropdowncolumn.html)

Dick